# Permutation of a mixture of (anti)commuting variables and consistency issue regarding the sign

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations, grassmannians

I asked a similar question in [PhysicsSE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/801870/how-to-generalize-the-anticommutation-for-spacelike-separation-to-more-than-2) but it seems more like a mathematical issue, so I post here in a more refined form.

I am not confident if the below description of the problem makes sense. Please let me know if there is anything insufficient.

For $n >2$, let us consider $n$ variables $a_1, \cdots, a_n$, each of which is either "bosonic" or "fermionic". Here the terms boson / fermion mean that

1. If at least one of $a$ and $b$ is bosonic, then $a,b$ commute : $ab=ba$.
2. If both of $a$ and $b$ are fermionic, then $a,b$ anticommute : $ab=-ba$.

Now, for any given permutation $\sigma \in S_n$. let us define
\begin{equation}
\sigma \cdot \bigl(a_1 \cdots a_n \bigr):= a_{\sigma(1)} \cdots a_{\sigma(n)}
\end{equation}

It is well-known that any permutation can be written as a product of adjacent transpositions. So, following the above two (anti)commutation rules for adjacent transpositions, we can figure out the correct sign for:
\begin{equation}
\sigma \cdot \bigl(a_1 \cdots a_n \bigr)=\pm a_1 \cdots a_n 
\end{equation}

Here, my problem arises.

> Representation of a permutation in terms of adjacent transpositions is NOT unique, cf. [ME](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4384688/is-the-decomposition-of-a-permutation-into-adjacent-transpositions-unique). Hence, I am concerned if different representations of given $\sigma$ may yield different signs, thereby causing "inconsistency" of the sign.

For example, let us consider $a_1, a_2, a_3$ where $a_1, a_2$ are fermionic and $a_3$ is bosonic. We know that $(1,2)(2,3)(1,2)=(2,3)(1,2)(2,3)$. Then, at least we can check that
\begin{equation}
\Bigl[ (1,2)(2,3)(1,2) \Bigr] \cdot (a_1a_2a_3) =-\Bigl[ (1,2)(2,3) \Bigr] \cdot (a_2a_1a_3) =-\Bigl[ (1,2) \Bigr] \cdot (a_2a_3a_1) = -a_3a_2a_1
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\Bigl[ (2,3)(1,2)(2,3) \Bigr] \cdot (a_1a_2a_3) =\Bigl[ (2,3)(1,2) \Bigr] \cdot (a_1a_3a_2) =\Bigl[ (2,3) \Bigr] \cdot (a_3a_1a_2) = -a_3a_2a_1
\end{equation}
so that the sign is consistent in this case. However, how can we prove such consistency for arbitrary $n$ and $\sigma \in S_n$?

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: So an attempt at a rigorous interpretation would be to say that we are considering the algebra of polynomials (over $\mathbb C$, I suppose) in $n$ non-commuting variables $a_1,\ldots , a_n$, modulo the (anti-)commutation rules you imposed (?).

Comment: And you are trying to show that $a_{\sigma(1)}\ldots a_{\sigma(n)}\not= 0$ always in this algebra.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Yes, that seems like a right interpretation.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I am trying to show that $a_{\sigma(1)} \cdots a_{\sigma(n)} = \pm a_{1} \cdots a_{n}$ where the sign $\pm$ holds independently of any representation of $\sigma$ in terms of adjacent transpositions.

Comment: @ChristianRemling The example of $a_1, a_2, a_3,$ and $(1,2)(2,3)(1,2)$, $(2,3)(1,2)(2,3)$ illustrates my concern clearly, I hope.

Comment: @ChristianRemling My concern is not on $a_{\sigma(1)} \cdots a_{\sigma(n)} \neq 0$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Hmm...Could you explain more how zero in the quotient is related to "sign consistency" in the quotient I am concerned about?

Comment: Let $A=\mathbb C\langle a_1, \ldots, a_n\rangle$ be the algebra of polynomials in non-commuting variables. Then I suggest to formalize your question by considering $B=A/I$, where $I$ is the ideal generated by the $a_ja_k\pm a_ka_j$. This I can do whether or not the property you are trying to establish holds, and if it doesn't, it means that such a product $p\in A$ is in $I$, so $(p)=0$ in $B$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I see. Then, could you explain more why you said "inconsistencies are ruled out by definition"?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464452/permutation-of-a-mixture-of-anticommuting-variables-and-consistency-issue-rega#comment1206302_464452), inconsistencies are ruled out in the sense that we know that multiplication in $A/I$ is independent of the representatives, and that's a general fact about quotient rings.  Perhaps it is easier to see that inconsistencies are *hidden*, in the sense that, if two re-writings would lead to different signs, then the relevant product is $0$ *because we already know it's well defined*.

Comment: @LSpice the word "hidden" seems to imply that inconsistencies "exist", which is surely not what you mean?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464452/permutation-of-a-mixture-of-anticommuting-variables-and-consistency-issue-rega#comment1206342_464452), what I mean is that there could potentially be (except I guess that @ChristianRemling has [shown](https://mathoverflow.net/a/464474) that there can't) things that *look* like inconsistencies in the free anti-commuting polynomial algebra $A$, but that, *by definition*, no such inconsistencies are visible in the quotient $A/I$, because passing to the quotient identifies two products if the (order and) images of the factors are the same.

Comment: @LSpice Ok I see.

Comment: If you want a superpolynomial algebra with $n$ bosonic indeterminates $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ and $m$ fermionic indeterminates $y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_m$, you can just take the tensor product $K\left[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\right] \otimes K_\wedge\left[y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_m\right]$ of the bosonic and fermionic parts. You need no special combinatorics for this.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thnk you. What I was concerned was consistency of sign, not combinatorics. Perhaps are they relared?

Comment: Well, the consistency of signs follows from the fact that monomials that include at most one copy of each $y_j$ form a basis of the superpolynomial algebra. And this is an immediate consequence of the fact that a basis of a tensor product can be obtained by tensoring together bases of the two factors. You don't need to reprove this combinatorially.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a rewriting $\sigma\cdot a\to a$ following your (anti-)commutation rules, remove all the bosonic variables. Then you still have a valid rewriting $\sigma'\cdot f\to f$. Now if there were a second rewriting $\sigma\cdot a\to -a$, then we would also get to $-f$ from $\sigma'\cdot f$.

This, however, is impossible since when only anti-commuting variables are involved, the final sign depends only on the parity of the number of (adjacent) transpositions, which is determined by the sign of $\sigma'$.

(To make the connection with the more highbrow approach advertised above, in the comments, what I'm doing here is apply the partial evaluation homomorphism $b_j\mapsto 1$ between the full algebra and the one with just the fermionic variables.)

Comment: Well, the crucial issue is how to "remove all bosonic variables" and define $\sigma'$ even when $\sigma$ mixes bosons and fermions altogether?

Comment: When there was a bosonic variable involved, you switched two commuting variables originally, and in the $'$ version, you do nothing. For example $f_2bf_1\to b f_2f_1\to -bf_1f_2$ becomes $f_2f_1\to f_2f_1\to -f_1f_2$. (Even clearer perhaps if you replace $b$ with $1$ and then run the first sequence literally.)

Comment: As for $\sigma'$, I just read this off by comparing the original ordering of the $f_j$ with $f_1f_2\ldots f_m$.

Comment: Ah...I can see your point.. Just one more question : what do you mean by "original ordering of $f_j$" in your previous comment?

Comment: If $(a_1, \ldots , a_n)=(f_1,\ldots , f_m, b_1, \ldots b_p)$, then $\sigma\cdot a$ in particular reorders the $f_j$, and that was my "original ordering" above. But you can just say that if you remove the $b_j$ from $\sigma\cdot a$, then $\sigma'$ is simply the permutation that maps $(f_1,\ldots , f_m)$ to whatever you are looking at now.

Comment: I see. And what you just said applies to "any" mixture of $f_i$'s and $b_j$'s in place of the $(a_1, ..., a_n)$ you just considered?

Comment: Yes, the $f$'s and $b$'s are the $a$'s in your notation, it's just convenient to indicate the type of a given variable.

Comment: What I meant is that instead of $(f_1, ..., f_m, b_1, ...,b_p)$, some more "mixed enumeration" such as $(b_1, f_1, f_2, b_2 ,....)$.

Comment: @Isaac, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464452/permutation-of-a-mixture-of-anticommuting-variables-and-consistency-issue-rega#comment1206337_464474), any change of variables, between arbitrary mixed enumerations, can be handled by changing to and from an intermediate "sorted" representation, so we need only consider such representations.